# dustjs load from database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, dust.js

I am new using dustjs and I want to use it to render a template with information from mongo using mongoose.

So I have:

- A template:

  ```
   {"This object property {object1} is loaded from db"}
  ```
- object1 is a string loaded with mongoose from mongodb

I need a generic function with some parameters in the context to make the query. Something like

```
{
   object1: function(objectid){
               Object.findOne({_id: objectid},function(err,ob){
                              return ob.property;
                              })
                              }
}
```

Is that possible with dustjs?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure i understand what you want to do, but if you want to pass in a parameter, you're looking at probably defining a section instead of just a context.

you could do this:

```
{"This object property {object1 objectid="1"}{.}{/object1} is loaded from db"}
```

and your method in the context will have to have these parameters:

```
object1: function(chunk, context, bodies, params){
  var objectid = params.objectid;
  <the rest of your code>
  return chunk.write(ob.property)
}
```

if a parameter is what you're looking for, dust will only allow parameters for sections. and you can do this no problem. good luck.